# Where can I find numeric keycodes to use with keyPress command in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, keycode

At http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html there's description of *keySequence* parameter to *keyPress* command:

> Either be a string("\" followed by the numeric keycode of the key to
>   be pressed, normally the ASCII value of that key), or a single
>   character. For example: "w", "\119".

Nevertheless there's no information on where to look for numeric keycodes to use...

Comment: There is [plenty of information](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ascii+table) on which codes to use.

Comment: There is plenty of information with different mappings and that's why I ask which one is the right one in **this particular** context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx

This works for me

Comment: Or this one - http://www.webonweboff.com/tips/js/event%5Fkey%5Fcodes.aspx Btw, I had to use *keyDown* as *keyPress* was not working for me.

Comment: @Piotr Dobrogost : true, the problem i usually faced with keypress was that its not interpreted by all browsers alike. most commonly the escape key with value 27 wouldn't work for me most of the times. But keyup and keydown seemt o have consistent handling across browsers. so now i usually use keyup/keydown rather than keypress whereever i can

Answer (score 0):

What you need are the ascii codes of the number characters, as an example, see the following page:

http://www.asciitable.com/

The numbers go from \48 (0) to \57 (9).

Comment: I've seen this table but it lacks information on codes of special keys like `Home` etc.

Comment: Ah sorry, then you mean this: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/l/blvkc.htm (keep in mind they're in hexa)

Answer (score 0):

The modules have objects/variables for the common keys, e.g.:

Ruby: http://www.google.com/codesearch#2tHw6m3DZzo/trunk/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.rb
Python: http://www.google.com/codesearch#2tHw6m3DZzo/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/keys.py
Java: http://www.google.com/codesearch#2tHw6m3DZzo/trunk/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.java

I believe these mappings include most of the special keys you're looking for?

Comment: Ack, sorry, didn't realize you were using RC and not webdriver . . . ignore this answer ;)

Comment: These are mappings to Unicode *Private Use Area* codepoints and tell nothing about actual numeric codes used in a browser as far as I see.

Comment: The above links are unfortunately returning 404 not found at this time.